# Saving different presets with python

Tags: python, parsing

for my espresso machine I am programming a GUI in Python with PyQt5.
I want to save different "profiles" which I can recall depending on the bean I am using.
There is a firmware (from the machine called "decent espresso machine") written in TCL which shows what I want (I will attach 2 images and a snippet of one of those description files, line 1 in this file contains the different steps).

I am not sure which parser I should use. I obviously always want to save different values for the same parameters (in c I would say the same struct), so somehow it feels wrong to use someting like configparser where you always have independent sections.

Can somebody give me a hint what lib I should use. There are always the same parameters, but the different recipes may contain different amount of steps.

I would like to have something like this pseudocode:

```
recipe=open('recipe1.txt')
currentstep=0
for steps in recipe:
    pressure = step[currentstep].pressure
    flow = step[currentstep].flow
    ...
    brew()
    currentstep = currentstep + 1
```

[Steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTAgG.png)
[Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoYck.png)

This is in the TCL file:

```
advanced_shot {{exit_if 1 flow 6.0 volume 100 transition fast exit_flow_under 0 temperature 90.0 name infuse pressure 1 sensor coffee pump flow exit_type pressure_over exit_flow_over 6 exit_pressure_over 3.0 exit_pressure_under 0 seconds 20.0} {exit_if 0 volume 100 transition fast exit_flow_under 0 temperature 90.0 name {rise and hold} pressure 9.0 sensor coffee pump pressure exit_flow_over 6 exit_pressure_over 11 seconds 10.0 exit_pressure_under 0} {exit_if 1 volume 100 transition smooth exit_flow_under 0 temperature 90.0 name decline pressure 4.0 sensor coffee pump pressure exit_type pressure_under exit_flow_over 1.2 exit_pressure_over 11 seconds 20.0 exit_pressure_under 4.0} {exit_if 1 flow 1.2 volume 100 transition smooth exit_flow_under 0 temperature 90.0 name {pressure limit} pressure 4.0 sensor coffee pump pressure exit_type flow_over exit_flow_over 1.0 exit_pressure_over 11 exit_pressure_under 0 seconds 10.0} {exit_if 0 flow 1.0 volume 100 transition smooth exit_flow_under 0 temperature 90.0 name {flow limit} pressure 3.0 sensor coffee pump flow exit_flow_over 6 exit_pressure_over 11 seconds 30.0 exit_pressure_under 0}}
author Decent
beverage_type espresso
espresso_decline_time 30
espresso_hold_time 15
espresso_pressure 6.0
espresso_temperature 90.0
final_desired_shot_volume 32
final_desired_shot_volume_advanced 0
final_desired_shot_weight 32
final_desired_shot_weight_advanced 36
flow_profile_decline 1.2
flow_profile_decline_time 17
flow_profile_hold 2
flow_profile_hold_time 8
flow_profile_minimum_pressure 4
flow_profile_preinfusion 4
flow_profile_preinfusion_time 5
preinfusion_flow_rate 4
preinfusion_guarantee 1
preinfusion_stop_pressure 4.0
preinfusion_time 20
pressure_end 4.0
profile_hide 0
profile_language en
profile_notes {An advanced spring lever profile by John Weiss that addresses a problem with simple spring lever profiles, by using both pressure and flow control. The last two steps keep pressure/flow under control as the puck erodes, if the shot has not finished by the end of step 3. Please consider this as a starting point for tweaking.}
profile_title {Advanced spring lever}
settings_profile_type settings_2c
tank_desired_water_temperature 0
water_temperature 80
```

Comment: use the pickle module

Comment: Are you asking how to parse a Tcl file in Python?

Comment: I'd make a class that has each of those items, then come up with a custom decoder to parse/decode/encode the file, then use json or pickle (json for more readable output) to store it, or sqlite.